# Update Panel refreshes whole page

Tags: asp.net, listbox, updatepanel

On a masterpage I have my scriptmanager with enablepartialrendering is true.
On the page I have a usercontrol, on this usercontrol is an update panel with Updatemode is conditional.

It's about two listboxes that swapped an item from the left listbox to the right listbox by clicking on an imagebutton. (This works fine)

The two imagebuttons are in a div block for the stylesheet.
I use the postbacktrigger for them.
Still the whole page refreshes, what am I doing wrong?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DoubleListBox.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="site.Controls.DoubleListBox" %>
<div class="formfield ff_itemswapper">
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" />
<div class="itemswapper">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelListboxes" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lsbFrom" runat="server" CssClass="is_current"></asp:ListBox>
            <div class="is_transfers" runat="server">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imb_Left" runat="server" CssClass="is_transfer_in" ImageUrl="../Images/gfx/arrow_left.png"
                    OnClick="imbLeft_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="img_Right" runat="server" CssClass="is_transfer_out" ImageUrl="../Images/gfx/arrow_right.png"
                    OnClick="imgRight_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
            </div>
            <asp:ListBox ID="lsbTo" runat="server" CssClass="is_source"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imb_Left" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="img_Right" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The listbox is registered in the aspx page by

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/DoubleListBox.ascx" TagName="DoubleListBox" TagPrefix="lsb" %>
```

And called by:

```
<lsb:DoubleListBox ID="lsbPractise" runat="server" />
```

Comment: If you need more code, please ask for it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what a `PostBackTrigger` does.

A `PostBackTrigger` causes a full page postback, whereas an `AsyncPostBackTrigger` does an AJAX call from within the `UpdatePanel`. All elements inside the `UpdatePanel` *automatically* call `AsyncPostBackTrigger`s and all elements outside the panel call `PostBackTrigger`s.

So, to solve your problem, simply remove your entire `Triggers` section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I removed the triggers section and still it refreshed the whole page. And true I allways confuse them so I found this on asp.net. AsyncPostBackTrigger
Converts postbacks into async callbacks
Typically used to trigger updates when controls outside an UpdatePanel post back
If ChildrenAsTriggers="false", can be used to specify which controls inside UpdatePanel should call back rather than post back
PostBackTrigger
Lets controls inside UpdatePanel post back
Typically used to allow certain controls to post back when ChildrenAsTriggers="true"

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying you fixed the problem, but removing the triggers section *and* the `UpdateMode="Conditional"` line should fix it. You want the default behavior of the `UpdatePanel`. Your code is not complex enough to need to change the default value of `ChildrenAsTriggers`.

Comment: Thanks again! I did what you suggested but still it did not work (yet). What's next????

Comment: Do you have any properties set on the script manager? If so, try it without them because this should be working.

Comment: Yes, I have EnablePartialrendering ="true" OK I will try. thanks anyway I removed this property and it worked perfectly!! thanks